# Linkedin auto-share posts bot

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, linkedin-api, bots

I am trying to build a little in-house tool **to automate my LinkedIn experience.**

I am running a **python / selenium / phantomJS** combination.

What I would ideally like my script to do is:

1. **Auto login** to my LinkedIn account
2. **Check** other users' posts, like or shares that appear on my timeline
3. **Share to my connections** those posts containing a specific
   keyword. (for example, if a friend of mine posts about "machine learning", I would like to share that post)

For now I only manage to solve 1), using the following simple code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, random, sys, time, urlparse
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Check if the file 'config' exists, otherwise quit
if os.path.isfile('config') == False:
   print 'Error! No configuration file.'
sys.exit()

print '\nLaunching PhantomJS (light)'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.desired_capabilities['userAgent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36'
browser.desired_capabilities['javascriptEnabled'] = False
browser.desired_capabilities['loadImages'] = False
browser.desired_capabilities['webSecurityEnabled'] = False

# Open, load and close the 'config' file
with open('config', 'r') as configFile:
   config = [line.strip() for line in configFile]
configFile.close()

# Sign in
browser.get('https://linkedin.com/uas/login')
emailElement = browser.find_element_by_id('session_key-login')
emailElement.send_keys(config[0])
passElement = browser.find_element_by_id('session_password-login')
passElement.send_keys(config[1])
passElement.submit()

print 'Signing in...'
time.sleep(4)
```

**The above code manages to auto-login**

However, when it comes to 2) (**check posts**) and 3) (**auto-share**), I am stuck...

I think that I found a lead though: after I sign-in with my selenium browser instance, I identify the following interesting items that may lead to the solution

```
<li class="feed-update member-like-share has-snippets">
```

and

```
<li class="feed-update member-share-article has-snippets">
```

contain the box where people have shared posts, and

```
<button class="share">
```

is the code that points to the share button, nested within the above

Could anybody help on solving this problem, please?

Admittedly, I am not an expert and any help would be appreciated.

Kind Regards,
terzim

Comment: Hi guys, isn't there anyone able or willing to help? Should I re-formulate my question in a different way? Thanks a lot - terzim

Comment: have you had any success with this? I am looking to do number 3 on your list, but would actually like to skip number 1 if possible!

Comment: [linkedin-bot](https://github.com/JoshiAyush/inb), You can check this repository if any of the features you want has already implemented there.